# vbs run ps1 from any location

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to run ps1 script via VBS but it is only working for me when full path of PS1 is given. c:\scripts\test.ps1

works with full path 
`Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run("powershell.exe -noexit c:\scripts\test.ps1")`

But I need that I can move script to different locations there for fixed path is not gonna work for me.

I have tried placing PS1 in to same folder where vbs is bit still can't make it work

Not working as objShell.Run("powershell.exe -noexit test.ps1") nor objShell.Run("powershell.exe -noexit .\test.ps1")

Any help appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing the following to reference the local directory of the script.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run("powershell.exe -noexit .\test.ps1")
```

Comment: only these 2 line in new vbs works but as soon I add to existing then I get:

`.\test.ps1 : The term '.\test.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\test.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\test.ps1:String) [], CommandN
   otFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

This is what I run before:

Comment: `Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strKeyPath = "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\"
oShell.RegWrite strKeyPath & "EnableScripts", "1", "REG_DWORD"
Set oShell = Nothing`

Comment: The `.\test.ps1` bit will only work if you have the test.ps1 file in the current working directory.  Check this link out for a bit more info from Microsoft - [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156586.aspx)

Comment: I think I know where the problem is. 

I'm runing vbs from mapped drive and vbs have evalation.

When I run outside evaltion its working
objShell.Run("powershell.exe -noexit .\test.ps1")

but when it evalted script don't work,